# Does VS2010 does not install SQL Server during installation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

Just confirming -does VS2010 does not install SQL Server during installation?  I'm assuming no.

This being the case I therefore need to download a copy of SQL Express 2005 or something to develop against on my windows XP home PC?  Is this correct?   Or would the Dev edition of SQL Server 2005 run/install on Windows XP Home?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed VS2010 Professional and it installed a 32 bit SQL Express 2008 instance as part of the install.

Comment: Like most things though, this is optional.

Comment: perhaps I didn't choose it - I might pull the disk out and have a look if I can install subsequently